Replacing a string in an array using sed
I have the following file
<path name="headphones-hifi-dac-advanced">
    <ctl name="Es9018 Master Volume" value="0" />
    <ctl name="Es9018 AVC Volume" value="0" />
    <ctl name="Es9018 HEADSET TYPE" value="2" />
</path>

<path name="headphones-hifi-dac-aux">
    <ctl name="Es9018 Master Volume" value="0" />
    <ctl name="Es9018 AVC Volume" value="0" />
    <ctl name="Es9018 HEADSET TYPE" value="3" />
</path>

<path name="headphones-hifi-dacdop">
    <ctl name="Es9018 Master Volume" value="15" />
    <ctl name="Es9018 AVC Volume" value="1" />
    <ctl name="Es9018 HEADSET TYPE" value="1" />
</path>

<path name="headphones-hifi-dacdop-advanced">
    <ctl name="Es9018 Master Volume" value="0" />
    <ctl name="Es9018 AVC Volume" value="0" />
    <ctl name="Es9018 HEADSET TYPE" value="2" />
</path>

I want to replace each Es9018 Master Volume entries' values to a distinct one, see below:
<path name="headphones-hifi-dac-advanced">
    <ctl name="Es9018 Master Volume" value="5" />
    <ctl name="Es9018 AVC Volume" value="0" />
    <ctl name="Es9018 HEADSET TYPE" value="2" />


</path>

<path name="headphones-hifi-dac-aux">
    <ctl name="Es9018 Master Volume" value="15" />
    <ctl name="Es9018 AVC Volume" value="0" />
    <ctl name="Es9018 HEADSET TYPE" value="3" />
</path>

<path name="headphones-hifi-dacdop">
    <ctl name="Es9018 Master Volume" value="20" />
    <ctl name="Es9018 AVC Volume" value="1" />
    <ctl name="Es9018 HEADSET TYPE" value="1" />
</path>

<path name="headphones-hifi-dacdop-advanced">
    <ctl name="Es9018 Master Volume" value="0" />
    <ctl name="Es9018 AVC Volume" value="0" />
    <ctl name="Es9018 HEADSET TYPE" value="2" />
</path>``

How do I achieve that using a sed logic?
I attempted
sed -i "/ *<path name=\"headphones-hifi-dac\">/a\     <ctl name=\"Es9018 AVC Volume\" value=\"0\" \/>"
But it ended up creating new entries instead of replacing current

Have you looked into XSLT for transforming XML, or at the very least a library for a programming language to parse and manipulate the XML? sed really doesn't seem like the right tool for this.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -E '1{x;s/^/'$(seq -s, 5 5 100)'/;x}
        /Es9018 Master Volume/{G
          s/(value=").*(".*\n)([^,]*),/\1\3\2/;P;s/.*\n//;h;d}' file

Initialize the hold space with unique values for the volume (here from 5 in steps of 5 to the value of 100, if more are needed increase the last value of the seq command).
When a line contains Es9018 Master Volume, append the unique values and using substitution replace the current value by the first value in the list. Then print the amended line and replace the hold space by the depleted list.
Repeat.
